# Regex select entire line that contains at least one uppercase letter

Tags: regex, visual-studio

title says it all. Among few others, I already tried:

```
.*[A-Z].*\r\n
[A-Z]

[A-Z]\r\n
```

I am trying to find:

```
    Gasdjsa1 = match
gsadjsa1 = nomatch
hasdaGas = match
1321831 = nomatch
asdGST_as = match
31hThsaA= match
```

I am using Visual Studio but i can also do it with ATOM if needed.

Comment: `^.*[A-Z].*$` should work so long as the single line flag is set correctly.

Comment: @RobertMcKee i guess my lines flag are not set correctly, i have a normal txt with one line under another

Comment: @RobertMcKee tried your solution but it selects everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using visual studio 2019 find (control-f), then select both the match case, and regex buttons.  Then use the regex `(?m)^.*[A-Z].*$`

[image]

Comment: `.*[A-Z].*` is enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well, not exactly, because find next will just move one character instead of to the next line that matches.  Although `^.*[A-Z].*` might be enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is not enough, already tried!